# Systemctl - Failed to get properties/Failed to list units

Tags: linux, rhel, system-calls

When try to execute systemctl commands as a normal user i get following errors, It can be executed using `root` user:

```
$ systemctl status firewalld
Failed to get properties: Operation not permitted

$ systemctl
Failed to list units: Operation not permitted
```

RHEL 7.3 / 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64

Any reasons behind this?

Comment: that's inside a docker container, isn't it?

Comment: Did you exec it as root?

Answer (score 1):

I found that the selinux on the server was enabled. 
After setting selinux to permissive. The error disappeared.

Comment: I have `SELINUX=disabled` and yet I am getting this error.

Comment: Never mind... `sestatus` was showing that it is enabled, so I guess the system was not rebooted after it was disabled. After a reboot, `sestatus` confirmed that selinux was disabled and the error did go away.